# How to get read only field values in controller using spring mvc.?

Tags: java, html, spring

is there any chance to get read only field values in controller either using annotations or some others in Spring.???

read only field contains text values.

ex:

`<form:input path="reqField" readonly="true"/>`

i want to get that read only field value in my controller using annotations or spring related technologies.

Or:

**In Controller :**

if (true) {

```
form.getReqField().asTransient();//will make variable as transient.
```

}

**Note :** Dont want to update read only fields once these have saved with some value.

Comment: What are the read only field values?

Comment: do you mean html textbox ??

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `readonly` html input values, then they are already submitted with the form and you can read them the same way you read other variables.

But if you mean `disabled` html input values, then you can add a `hidden` html input element that has the same `name` and  `value` attributes, and they will be submitted with your form

```
<input name="first_name" value="John" type="hidden" />
<input name="first_name" value="John" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```